# Getting undefined value in firebase Nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Getting undefined value in firebase when pushing the new node through android code but when adding manually means in firebase database directly then I am getting data. Unable to figure out what's wrong here.

```
exports.onUserCreated = functions.database.ref('/fcm/{pushId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context ) => {
      // Do something when a new user is created
      var email = snapshot.val().userid;
      var name = snapshot.val().username;
      var score = snapshot.val().desc;

      console.log(name);
      console.log(email);
      console.log(score);

      return sendWelcomeEmaill(email, name, score);
    });

function sendWelcomeEmaill(email, name, score){
    const mailOptions = {
        from :  `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
        to: email,
      };

    mailOptions.subject = `Score in Quiz ${APP_NAME}!`;
    mailOptions.html = `Hey ${name || ''}! Your score in ${APP_NAME} Quiz is ${score}.<br />
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5gapf20jRXFQ7XchrHByzUDQfZUPccJ417emPwHJNlY72dcazXi_X3urzAGq3f2rXPjlNlZmxj0fuiy88tJ3exVQuA6XEt6Dm4kFlq1efWtWh3f1gMZ8humwKjds3uWX-a8kxODCNym7xfT9CwjwPMGy_LapGBbdwbxn2v0KdgCW12gHXOElqRmSKCOZlLRVVQ5FrFkwjm4rp9EtbJngPbOASMoAVVGMucfsMRqX2KHRpKnvgsvDw4v8I7EgyvlF_59eAsnjUclzZHbTR7PMSDes9RC883H6h2oWt6ZiJ5--cp1dijI0-zap5M30RvCQzSXKAoDX1CkuwhRuzkBSa4ffYa1uq9Z38IcGxPFzZcyKMSG1sc7XRQE1oxSedkx8knlX46194-nyqkwxxVwvas3emTgPpGH_AjaW1BAZPLJl4B8Sks3hQg8S9gF492dNppgFiZV6pGELZ2glbQDD8o5S-Lj9vtYUjQb1tu9892zxPEqkGwqaVZ2buFnNgPm3iZKi8jS7WpjIzvJoXsMJ8y9LoT7l8N5xStOTMa6MKsol3-lT89y3UHHflPFmdHV42K_HnGi806_iNvFlgo5Czg0ZYBXCicwJCryu6ND2qASEQCIbHOVBmzyqUK-BhTj4HzDuHsIu_j7WJITqowxEleI=w69-h52-no">
    <br/>We hope you will enjoy our service. <br/> `;

    return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
      return console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
    });
}
```

Wait but getting the userid in both the methods . If my question is not clear please ask me in comment.

Case 1 screenshot [when adding data through android code]

[image]

Case2 screenshot when adding manually [working]

[image]

Here is my android code for pushing data in firebase

```
mDatabase3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("fcm");

mDatabaseUser1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                // long i =  -1* new Date().getTime();

                //  String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                String id = acct.getEmail();
                Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();

                final DatabaseReference newPost3 = mDatabase3.push();

                //  high.child(cleanEmail).setValue(finalValue);

                //high.child(node).setValue(finalValue);


                // newPost3.child(user_id).child("time").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                // newPost3.child(user_id).child("uid").setValue(mCurrentUser.getUid());
                newPost3.child("userid").setValue(acct.getEmail());

                newPost3.child("desc").setValue(finalValue);
              //  newPost3.child("userimage").setValue(personPhoto.toString());
                newPost3.child("username").setValue(acct.getDisplayName()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {



                        }


                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: You should share the Android code used to "push the new node" and not only the Cloud Function code. Do you see the data pushed by the Android app in the database console?

Comment: Yep @RenaudTarnec android code is pushing the data in write way

Comment: And you confirm that when you add the data manually through the console it does works perfectly?

Comment: Yep @RenaudTarnec I just checked again by adding data manually and it is working

Comment: Could you make a screen shot of the two different cases: one node where you added data manually and the other one when you added through the Android app?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Sure just wait for one minute

Comment: Are you sure that you create a new node with the Android code and not modify an existing one?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I added the screenshots of nodes please check it

Comment: Hmmm.. strange. Do you see any error in the Cloud Function log?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec no not getting any error in log but when I add data manually there I can see the information in console but when through android code the result is undefined value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186919/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-manik).

Comment: If the problem only happens when you add the data through your Android code, share the Android code that adds the data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure I will put my android code please allow me 2 minutes

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added my android code please check it

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is indeed what I expected: you're performing multiple write operations, only the first one of which triggers your Cloud Function. So the Cloud Function sees incomplete data. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `setValue()` or `updateChildren()` in a reference it results in data being written to the database. This means that in your code, the new node for the new user gets created after these statements:

```
final DatabaseReference newPost3 = mDatabase3.push();

newPost3.child("userid").setValue(acct.getEmail());
```

So at that point, the database only contains a `userid` for the new node. Since the node is now created, your Cloud Function gets triggered and `username` and `score` will be undefined at this point.

To prevent this from happening, you need to write the entire node for the new user in one call to the database. A simple way to do this, is to put all data in a `HashMap`:

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();

values.put("userid", acct.getEmail());
values.put("desc", finalValue);
values.put("username", acct.getDisplayName());

mDatabase3.push().setValue(values);
```

Comment: Sir you are genius I struggled for more than 12 hours for this issue and you solved it one go. Thank you so much .  My one request if you found this question helpful for future visitors please up vote this question.

Comment: Well spotted Frank!

Comment: @Frank you mean when newPost.child("userid").setValue(acct.getEmail()); add in database it triggers the functions and that's the reason the other child values are not reachable by cloud function ???

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it. Give it a try: run the Android code that creates a node through a debugger and step through the `setValue()` statements. You'll see that after the first `setValue()` the `/fcm/{pushId}` node is created already, and thus your Cloud Function gets triggered with only the child property that exists at that time.